# Debian Squeeze character encoding issue

Tags: linux, debian, character-encoding, debian-squeeze

I'm running Debian 6.0.7 (Squeeze). Normally, to get the euro symbol, I would type altgr-$ and this works fine on Ubuntu but with Squeeze when I hit those keys the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the previously typed word.

Can anyone tell me what needs setting up correctly.

Also, I'm running an application that needs to use the euro symbol and in a MySQL database that the app uses the euro symbol has been replaced by this: `â‚¬`.

Comment: The MySQL diagnostic looks like it's doing the right thing but you are using a misconfigured tool to examine the database.  Can you verify that the tool you are using is correctly set up to use UTF-8?  Anyway, this is probably completely unrelated to the keyboard behavior (although, fixing your locale settings may remove that symptom too!)

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output from `locale` and information about your keyboard layout?